# Closest place to Addis Ababa where you can see wildlife

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, ethiopia

Where is the closest place to Addis where one can see wildlife?

I am particularly interested in the Gilada Baboons, but  I would also like to see birds, preferably in a natural setting.

[image]

As far as I understand most of the Ethiopian forest disappeared and near Addis, the Entoto only has Eucalyptus. Of course you can't expect to find much in this Ethiopian "unnatural" setting.

As far as I can tell, if you ask locals, they don't really understand the fascination that others have with these things. You never get a straight answer, only vague comments with what it seems to be a puzzled face. Even when you show some enthusiasm. Maybe because they take it for granted and don't care or maybe the opposite. So it seems even locals, from Addis, don't know where to find them.

The best information I could get was a "if you go North".

Comment: Aside from the baboons and birds, anything in particular? I know, wildlife doesn't seem that subjective, but New Zealand doesn't even have native mammals so we get insanely excited when we even see a squirrel :)

Comment: @MarkMayo well these ar what I would mostly like to see. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Gelada's you may find mostly in mountain terrain in the north of Ethiopia. You could be lucky even in Addis but I don't know any good spot. Better chances you could have around the rifts near [Aletu](http://osm.org/go/wtuhkJY--). If you go further and reach out until [Debre Sina](http://osm.org/go/wvF1Fy9?m=) you can see many of them easily. They are in use to human visitors and will let you come close. Nights in Debre Sina are usually very cold so be prepared if you gone stay.

I'm not too much into birds but before chasing them I would recommend letting them come to you. Because they are very much into teff grains you should pay a visit to a close Teff mill and ask for a kilo or two. People will call you crazy but birds will admire you for this little gems. After feeding them for a view days or weeks you will be greatly rewarded.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Any other animals worth telling / endemic in Ethiopia?

Answer (score 2):

If you travel 100km North of Addis Ababa at Debrelibanos Monastery you will find Gelada Baboon. The confusion you have is asking the wrong person. there is tourist Information center in the city at Meskel Aquare and also at the Airport or Easily google on the Internet about The nearest wildlife area in Addis Ababa.
You will find the result such as
- Menagesha Suba Forest about 50km from Addis Ababa (reach in Indigneous trees and wildlifes)
- Awash National Park about 200km from Addis Ababa (reach in flora and Fauna)
- Gefersa Lake about 30 km from Addis Ababa (The best spot for aquatic birdwatching)
- and many more 
For more information please look the link below you will get a lot of information about Tourist Attraction of Addis Ababa and its surrounding
Short Day Excurison from addis: www.addistour.com